# How do I Query on Splunk Dashboard information

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

We are currently using ADO (pipeline artifacts) to Splunk for Build step reviews. I am working on a project to migrate Splunk Dashboards to powerbi. I need a query to list down the Dashboards and reports from Splunk on the below criteria so we would identify which ones to be created in powerbi

1. List of Dashboards / reports (possibly with Author details)
2. frequency of usage - like how many times the Dashboard / reports was viewed in the last 30 days

I tried few queries from mysplunk but it did not give the result. Thanks for any inputs / suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would help to know what you've tried so far.

To get a list of dashboards, try this query:

`| rest /servicesNS/-/-/data/ui/views`

To see which dashboards have been viewed, search the Splunk UI access log.

```
index=_internal sourcetype=splunkd_ui_access
| rex "\\/data\\/ui\\/views\\/(?<dashboard>[^\?]+)"
| stats count by dashboard
```

Comment: The first query works to list the dashboards . But the second does not work. to identify the usage frequency. Thanks.

Comment: "Does not work" doesn't tell me much.  Have you tried running the query one statement at a time?  Do you have access to the _internal index?

Comment: Sorry I missed to elaborate . The Query does not give me any result (no result found with different Date range). I requested an admin to check if I have access. 

I used the below query to list the available index to query . Not sure if there is any other query to chec my access.

| eventcount summarize=false index=* | dedup index | fields index

Comment: If you get no results with `index=_internal earliest=-15min` then you don't have access.  Your test query checks regular indexes, but not internal ones.  Use `index=_*` for that.

Comment: Thanks. yes looks like I dont have access. Could you please tell me where should the admin provide access . I searched for the answers but looks like solutions are dated to 2016 or before.

Comment: Those answers probably are still correct as the method hasn't changed much.  The admin needs to assign to your account a role that has access to the internal indexes.  IIRC, the Power User role has that by default.  Otherwise, he can go to Settings->Access Controls->Roles (newer releases use Settings->Roles) and change the indexes allowed for a chosen role.  Then she goes to Settings->Access Controls->Users (or Settings->Users), selects your account, then adds the recently-modified role to it.

Comment: perfect. Thanks much :)

Answer (score 0):

The below queries worked for me ..

To list the Dashboards
| rest /servicesNS/-/-/data/ui/views | table title,app,owner,eai:data,description,updated,version

To list the reports
|rest /servicesNS/-/-/saved/searches |table title,app,owner

Please note this will list down the default dashboards from Splunk that you may want to filter out.

I am still working on the query for the usage frequency . Thanks.